# Not going inside .on("click") function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, onclick

I cant figure out why my code is not going inside the on click function.What am I doing wrong ?

```
let allDivsOnTheRightPane = rightPane.contents().find(".x-panel-body-noheader > div");
//change height of all expanded divs due to the newly added cases tab -->

        allDivsOnTheRightPane.not(casesTabHTML).each(function(){
            let self = this;
            let header = self.childNodes[0];
            console.log(header); // element is found properly
            $(header).on( "click", function () { // the debugger is not going inside and jumps to the end 
                let currentDiv = $(this).get(0); 
                $(this).arrive(".x-panel-body", arriveOptions, function () {
                    let xPanel = currentDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")[2];
                    let xPanelSub = xPanel.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
                    let xPanelSubSub = xPanelSub.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
                    let currentHeight = $(xPanelSub).height();
                    let newHeight = (currentHeight - 30) + "px";
                    $(xPanelSub).css("height", newHeight);
                    $(xPanelSubSub).css("height", newHeight);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: try .click(function()

Comment: You know that the click handler function doesn't run until a click registers, right? If you're looking line-by-line with the debugger, the handler won't run immediately when it's assigned.

Comment: Oh god , how stupid I am :D this answers my question :D

Comment: Thanks , I was able to debug and fix the code . I will never forget - first clicking , then debugging :D:D:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered above , the debugger will go inside a .on ("click".. ) function only after you perform the click.